# Including an external library in an android library package

Tags: android, gradle

I'm writing an android library to be used in my Unity android project in order to make use of an android library that doesn't have a good C# equivalent. The library itself is packaged and works fine, except when I run the application, I get an error:

```
AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/vision/face/FaceDetector$Builder;
```

Opening up my AAR I've noticed that the Google Vision library I'm using isn't in there, and since Unity can't install android libraries it can't resolve it.

How can I package my application with the library installed?

Here's  my `build.gradle` dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    provided fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    provided files('/Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Variations/mono/Release/Classes/classes.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:8.1.0'
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue, though in a roundabout and indirect way.

I managed to go to my m2repository and gain the AAR for the library, plus all of its dependencies,which I then also added as Android plugins in my Unity project.

This meant all of the classes were in scope.